# How to detect anonymous status in acmart?

Tags: acmart

This is what I'm doing:

```
\documentclass[sigplan,nonacm=true,anonymous=true]{acmart}
\newcommand\anon[1]{%
  \makeatletter\if@ACM@anonymous%
    XXX%
  \else%
    #1%
  \fi\makeatother%
}
\begin{document}
Hello, \anon{Jeff}!
\end{document}
```

I'm expecting it to print `Hello, XXX!`, but it prints `Hello, Jeff!`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you have the makeatletter makeatother in the wrong place move them before and after the definition

Comment: @DavidCarlisle you are right! Make it an answer, please, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `@` to be a letter when the definition is made, so

```
\documentclass[sigplan,nonacm=true,anonymous=true]{acmart}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\anon[1]{%
\if@ACM@anonymous
    XXX%
  \else
    #1%
  \fi
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Hello, \anon{Jeff}!
\end{document}
```

As it was the `\makeatletter` was doing nothing (as the following characters were already tokenized so `\if@ACM@anonymous` was interpreted as

```
\if @A%
  CM@anonymous
```

compared `@` with `A` so not an error, but always false.